# Change time of execution for Automysqlbackup

Tags: mysql

I run automysqlbackup in an Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS server hosted in google cloud.

The backup is executed daily, but I have not control over the time of execution. During the rush hour, the automysqlbackup runs and crashes the functionality as mysqld uses 400% of CPU according to the top command.

I have checked chron, but there is no entry as far as I can see.

How can I schedule it to a time like 2 am?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the cron entry and modify it. Several possibilities exist, and you should try each of them until you find how the backup is being run.

**View Root’s Cron Jobs**

```
sudo crontab -l
```

To edit Root's cron jobs:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

If you find the entry, reschedule it to 2am by changing the leading numbers to:

```
0 2 * * *  /path/to/automysqlbackup
```

**View a User’s Cron Jobs**

```
sudo crontab -u username -l
```

To edit username's cron jobs:

```
sudo crontab -u username -e
```

If you find the entry, reschedule it to 2am by changing the leading numbers to:

```
0 2 * * *  /path/to/automysqlbackup
```

**List Daily Cron Jobs**

```
sudo ls -la /etc/cron.daily/
```

Any cron jobs found in `/etc/cron.daily/` can be edited with `sudo vi`.
[This article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-when-does-cron-daily-weekly-monthly-run/) describes the contents of the file, which controls scheduling of this type of cron job. To summarize, be sure the contents include something like:

```
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
# RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=2-2

#period in days / delay in minutes / job-identifier  / command
1   0   cron.daily      nice backup /path/to/automysqlbackup
```

Comment: Thanks. I searched for crontab for root and user, but there are no crontabs for any user>>>>>>for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done

Comment: That incantation did not work for me, but this does: `for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do sudo crontab -u $user -l; done`

Comment: @MikeSlinn In `/etc/cron.daily/automysqlbackup` I have the following lines: `#!/bin/sh` `test -x /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup || exit 0` `/usr/sbin/automysqlbackup`. What does those mean? Can I delete the `automysqlbackup` folder from `/etc/cron.daily` and set everything up through `sudo crontab -u username -e` for my user?